# javascript functions stop working after writing another function in the same script

Tags: javascript, php, function, bootstrap-modal

Im doing am employee leave management system. The approve and disapprove buttons were working fine in the beginning. But after writing the code to show employee details in the same modal, the approve and disapprove buttons stopped working. Now it gives error. Does anyone have an idea on whats wrong?

**controller**

```
//admin approve leave 
public function approveLeave() {

    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $result = $this->Admin_Model->approve($id);

    if(!$result){

        // something went wrong

        $data = array(
            "value" => $id,
            "error" => true,                
            "msg" => "something went wrong"
        );

        $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output(json_encode($data));

        return;
    }


    // approved leave

    $data = array(
        "value" => $id,
        "error" => false,
        "msg" => "successfully updated"
    );

    $this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_output(json_encode($data));

}
```

**modal**

```
<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="pendingLeaveRequest" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Leave Request</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" id="leave_details" >
            <p> </p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="hidden" name="current_leave_id" id="current_leave_id" value="" />
            <button type="button" id="declinebtn" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Decline</button>
            <button type="button" id="approvebtn" class="btn btn-primary">Approve</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**javascript**

```
    <script> 

    $(function(){

    var BASE_URL = "http://localhost/employeemgt/index.php/";


        $('#pendingLeaveRequest').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
            var current_leave_id = button.data('id');
            var modal = $(this);

            modal.find('input[name="current_leave_id"]').val(current_leave_id); 
        });     



        //approve button
        $('#approvebtn').click(function(){              
            var id = $('input[name="current_leave_id"]').val();
                  $.post(BASE_URL +  'admin/AdminDashboardController/approveLeave', 
                    {'id': id}, 
                    function(result){
                        console.log(result);
                    if(result.error){                       
                        alert('try again');
                    }else{
                        alert('Leave has been approved!');
                    }
                });              
        });



       //disapprove button
        $('#declinebtn').click(function(){              
            var id = $('input[name="current_leave_id"]').val();
                  $.post(BASE_URL +  'admin/AdminDashboardController/disapproveLeave', 

                    {'id': id}, 
                    function(result){
                        console.log(result);
                    if(result.error){                       
                        alert('try again');
                    }else{
                        alert('Leave has been disapproved!');
                    }
                });              
        });

        });



        //show leave details on modal
    $('.detailButton').on('click', function(){
    var BASE_URL = "http://localhost/employeemgt/index.php/";
        var leave_id = $(this).val();
        var i;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "JSON",
            data:{leave_id:leave_id},
            url: BASE_URL + 'admin/AdminDashboardController/viewRequest',   

            success:function(data){                 
            console.log(data);
           $('#leave_details').html("<p>" + "Name: " + data[0].user_name + "</p>" + 
                                  "<p>" + "Leave Type: " + data[0].leave_type + "</p>"  + 
                                  "<p>" + "Start Date: " + data[0].leave_start + "</p>"  + 
                                  "<p>" + "End Date: " + data[0].leave_end + "</p>");       
            $('#pendingLeaveRequest').modal('show');
       },
       error:function(error){
            alert(error);
        }});
    });


</script>
```

**view**

```
<div id="showleave">
                <h4 class="mb-4">Pending Requests</h4>
                    <?php
                        foreach ($leave as $row) {  
                        if($row->status != "1")
                         {                          
                            echo '
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <li class="media border-bottom border-top py-3">
                                    <img class="mr-3" src="http://via.placeholder.com/64x64" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                      <h5 class="mt-0 mb-1">'.$row->user_name.'</h5>
                                      <p class="mb-0 mt-0">'.$row->leave_start.' to '.$row->leave_end.'</p>
                                      <p class="mt-0">'.$row->leave_type.'</p>
                                      <button type="button" class="detailButton" href="<?php echo $id; ?>" data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-name="'.$row->user_name.'" data-toggle="modal" value="'.$row->id.'">View Request</button>
                                    </div>
                                </li>               
                            </ul>
                            ';
                        }
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: It says try again when clicking approve or disapprove

Comment: Probably, "$('input[name="current_leave_id"]').val()" is returning an invalid or empty id. If that's the case, check "var current_leave_id = button.data('id');" line if the id is valid there.

Comment: Now no alert is coming. But in console it says button is not defined.

Comment: "pedingLeaveRequest" has a typo?

Comment: yes i have corrected it, but still approve and disapprove dont work

Comment: in $('#approvebtn').click(function(){}) and $('#declinebtn').click(function(){}) functions remove alert(" try again ") and add console.log(result.error) instead and then show error for me

Comment: can you access to server code (for you : BASE_URL +  'admin/AdminDashboardController/approveLeave )

Comment: do you mean the code in the controller?

Comment: this is a server side error , you should change server side service and show correct error message

Comment: yes in controller action

Comment: use try{ } cach(\Exception $e) and send error in cach

Comment: Sorry Im new this and havent use try catch practically. I have updated my above code

Comment: your problem is in this code : $result = $this->Admin_Model->approve($id); result is null or empty or false , approve method cant approve id you send , id is null , you send incorrect id

Comment: this line is incorrect : var id = $('input[name="current_leave_id"]').val();

Comment: value of input not set

Comment: how to send the correct id? How should it be corrected

Comment: I change my answer , check that

Comment: i changed my answer again

Answer (score 2):

Use

`$(document).on('click','#declinebtn',function(){})` instead of `$('#declinebtn').click(function(){})` .

change your view code like this :

```
<div id="showleave">
<h4 class="mb-4">Pending Requests</h4>
<?php
foreach ($leave as $row) {
    if($row->status != 1)
    {
        ?>

        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li class="media border-bottom border-top py-3">
                <img class="mr-3" src="http://via.placeholder.com/64x64" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 class="mt-0 mb-1"><?= $row->user_name ?></h5>
                    <p class="mb-0 mt-0"> <?= $row->leave_start.' to '.$row->leave_end ?></p>
                    <p class="mt-0"><?= $row->leave_type ?></p>
                    <button type="button" class="detailButton" href="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" data-id="<?= $row->id ?>" data-name="<?= $row->user_name ?>" data-toggle="modal" value="<?= $row->id ?>">View Request</button>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

By this I think your problem will be solve

Comment: No change yet. Still says try again

Comment: in $('#approvebtn').click(function(){}) and $('#declinebtn').click(function(){})  functions remove alert(" try again ")  and add console.log(result.error) instead and then show error for me

Comment: the console says "true"

Comment: says undefined variable: id

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
`$(document).on("click", "#approvebtn", function(event){
      // your code here
});`
And you can also try triggering your btn from browser console to check if it works.

Comment: Still no change. In the console it says {value: "", error: true, msg: "something went wrong"}
error
:
true
msg
:
"something went wrong"
value
:
""
__proto__
:
Object